# Iptables rules with dockerized web application - can't block incoming traffic

Tags: docker, iptables

i'm hosting a dockerized web application binded with port 8081 in my remote server.
I want to block that web application for external ips, as I already did wit port 8080 hosting a plain jenkins server.
Here's what i've tried:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d <my-server-ip> -p tcp --dport 8081 -j DROP
```

As I did with port 8080.

Here is

```
iptables -nv -L INPUT
```

output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2836 packets, 590K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
495 23676 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0             <my-ip-addr>        tcp dpt:8080
  0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0             <my-ip-addr>        tcp dpt:8081
```

Has it possibily something to do with DOCKER chain in iptables ?

```
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  9   568 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0       <container-eth1-addr>         tcp dpt:8080
```

There are more specific rules i need to add ?
Isn't my server INPUT rules supposed to be applied before those listed in the DOCKER chain?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Thanks to larsks's comments I found the solution.

The goal here was to block tcp traffic on port 8081 binded with docker docker container but being able to use ssh tunneling as "poor man" VPN (so non publish the port was not an option).
Just had to add this rule:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -d <container-eth-ip>  ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

Comment: Rules for Docker containers typically belong in the `FORWARD` chain of the filter table, but in fact you should add them to the `DOCKER_USER` chain, which Docker creates just for this purpose.

Comment: @larsks so in your opinion i should assign a static ip for the container interface and then drop tcp traffic on port 8080 (original port in the docker container) in DOCKER_USER chain ?

Comment: That's one option. If you want to affect the published port and not worry about a static container ip, you could add your rules to the `PREROUTING` chain of the `nat` table (before the `... -j DOCKER` rule). Or, if your goal is really to `DROP` everything, just don't publish the port.

Comment: I've just tried and it works perfectly for my purpose, thank you